# How to get nextProps in component that using memo but not rendering?

Tags: reactjs

**I want index of nextProps in functional component . If not pass in memo , component only use prevProps.**

> I need next props index in this component. Indexes are updated , but I don't want to re-render the component .

```
const TitleItems = props => {
   const {
           sel_mode,
           updateDataItem,
           index,
           item,
         } = props;
            
        const handleOnLongPress = () => {
             if (!sel_mode) {
                selModeON();
                updateDataItem({
                index: index,
                item: {
                   ...item,
                   checked: true,
                },
                });
            }
      };
      return(<>...</>);
 }
            
       const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
              const {index} = nextProps;
              const {index: prev_index} = prevProps;
              const isEqual = index === prev_index 
    // without these condition , it does not re-render in these case there is only prevProps in component
              return isEqual;
       };
export default React.memo(TitleItems, areEqual);
```

Comment: It looks like your question need more description, why the `index` in next props won't be there? Anyway, have you considered returning `true` to prevent rendering if the `index` doesn't exist

Comment: There is nextProps in areEqual . But not in functional component . How to get next props in component without re-render. Thanks you.

Comment: Indexs are change . but I only want updated index without re-rendering.

Comment: Okay I get you, the `next props` is the `props` itself, there is no `nextProps` in functional component, maybe we need more details on how you structure your component to help achieve what you want

Comment: where is the index is comming from?

Comment: Maybe you can make two nested components, the outer one get re-rendered when `index` change, but it won't re-render the inner component (because you can use the `memo`rization technique)

Comment: Indexes are comming from Flatlist.

Comment: I really can't see why you need to access the updated index without re-render, you are not using it, and if you are using it, it really should re-render to give you the updated value

Comment: you can also pass the index with reference object e.g. (`index = useRef(0)`) . For update use mutation `index.current = 5` for usage `<Comp index={index} />` and inside component reference it as `index.current`

Comment: I think update index is not effecting view , it only behind the scene , so I don't want to re-render view.

Comment: So the ref will be the thing you want I guess, it passed the latest index to be used on the logic side e.g. user interaction but doesn't cause update and re-render. If you want I can demonstrate how it works by ref passing (don't mess this thing with forwarding ref) I am referencing ref as the mutable object

Comment: How to pass that ref to component,  as a prop?,  props are not updated with memo that I am using.

Comment: don't you want to update the component for every prop expects index? if so you can remove the memo. if not I might not get your problem correctly. but there is always an option of what @MhdLouayAl-osh suggested, you might also want to see https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Not fairly related but it seems to react recoil tried to handle de-coupling issue, if you want to both separate and connect components to same part of state (here is index)